# python pandas - functionning of groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (lets call it "best_trades") that is such as follow:

```
                              exit_time  netgain_by_MAE
2000-02-01 07:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.083333
2000-02-01 08:30:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.625000
2000-02-01 09:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        3.312500
2000-02-01 09:30:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.000000
2000-02-01 10:30:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.312500
2000-02-02 13:30:00 2000-02-02 15:00:00        2.000000
2000-02-02 14:00:00 2000-02-02 15:00:00        2.428571
2000-02-02 15:00:00 2000-02-03 00:00:00        3.000000
2000-02-03 02:30:00 2000-02-03 07:30:00        2.000000
2000-02-03 10:00:00 2000-02-03 15:00:00        2.222222
2000-02-03 10:30:00 2000-02-04 00:00:00        3.259259
2000-02-03 11:00:00 2000-02-04 00:00:00        4.666667
2000-02-03 11:00:00 2000-02-04 01:00:00        2.629630
2000-02-03 11:00:00 2000-02-04 01:30:00       14.500000
2000-02-03 12:30:00 2000-02-04 01:30:00       11.600000
2000-02-03 13:00:00 2000-02-04 01:30:00        5.300000
2000-02-03 13:30:00 2000-02-04 01:30:00        2.700000
2000-02-03 14:00:00 2000-02-04 03:30:00        4.100000
2000-02-03 14:30:00 2000-02-04 03:30:00        2.600000
```

The dataframe represent a list of trades. 
The first column represent the entry time of the trade, the second the exit time, the 3rd column , a custom metric i created.

I would like to compute the highest value of netgain_by_MAE for trades that are overlapping in time, for instance those ones:

```
2000-02-01 07:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.083333
2000-02-01 08:30:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.625000
2000-02-01 09:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        3.312500
2000-02-01 09:30:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.000000
2000-02-01 10:30:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        2.312500
```

(here the result would be `2000-02-01 09:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        3.312500`)

I managed to retrieve those rows with the groupby function:
`best_trades = best_trades.groupby(['MAE_ts'])['netgain_by_MAE'].transform('max')`

However this returns a df such as follow:

```
2000-02-01 07:00:00     2.083333
2000-02-01 08:30:00     3.312500
2000-02-01 09:00:00     3.312500
2000-02-01 09:30:00     3.312500
2000-02-01 10:30:00     3.312500
2000-02-02 13:30:00     2.428571
...
```

How to keep the same columns as the original dataframe, only keeping the rows that have the max netgain_by_mae value for each groupby ?
(ie i would like to have the following output :

```
2000-02-01 09:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        3.312500
2000-02-02 14:00:00 2000-02-02 15:00:00        2.428571
2000-02-02 15:00:00 2000-02-03 00:00:00        3.000000
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly then all you must do is sort the DataFrame by exit time and netgain_by_MAE descending and then take the first row of each exit_time group.

```
df = best_trades.sort_values(['exit_time', 'netgain_by_MAE'], ascending=[True,False])\
                .groupby('exit_time')\
                .first()\
                .reset_index()

print(df[['entry_time', 'exit_time', 'netgain_by_MAE']])

            entry_time           exit_time  netgain_by_MAE
0 2000-02-01 09:00:00 2000-02-01 11:30:00        3.312500
1 2000-02-02 14:00:00 2000-02-02 15:00:00        2.428571
2 2000-02-02 15:00:00 2000-02-03 00:00:00        3.000000
3 2000-02-03 02:30:00 2000-02-03 07:30:00        2.000000
4 2000-02-03 10:00:00 2000-02-03 15:00:00        2.222222
5 2000-02-03 11:00:00 2000-02-04 00:00:00        4.666667
6 2000-02-03 11:00:00 2000-02-04 01:00:00        2.629630
7 2000-02-03 11:00:00 2000-02-04 01:30:00       14.500000
8 2000-02-03 14:00:00 2000-02-04 03:30:00        4.100000
```

Comment: that is great thx! However in my example the first column is the index (the "entry_time"). somehow when i run your code the result is simply missing that first column (it gives something like that): `0  2000-01-03 04:00:00    2.200000` . Any thought on how to keep that first timestamp index as the index?

Comment: use `reset_index` before doing the code above and then after the code above run `df.set_index('entry_time')`